# name "isJump" is not defined

Tags: python-3.7

Я новичок , только начал изучать Python . И вот появилась ошибка(как не проверял , все равно появляется сообщение об ошибке).Вот часть кода в котором ошибка по мнению консоли:

```
if not(isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y>5:
            y -= speed      
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y<800-height-15:
            y += speed  
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10 :
            if jumpCount < 0 :
                y+=(jumpCount**2)/2
            else:   
                y -= (jumpCount**2)/2
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount= 10
```

Comment: Ну, очевидно, у вас не существует переменной `isJump`. Несуществующую переменную использовать естественно невозможно. Больше добавить нечего

Comment: Спасибо , andreymal , уже обнаружил ошибку :)

Comment: как ты решил эту проблему с isJump?? такая же проблема